# Single or multiple spaces same as empty string in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I just found a strange behavior i Microsoft Access. When i run the code below i would expect that rs.EOF would be true. It is not. It turns out that any number of spaces is equal to any other number of spaces. Why this strange behavior?

```
Sub tmp()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    CurrentDb.Execute "create table table1 (id  counter, field1  text(10),primary key (id))"
    CurrentDb.Execute "insert into table1 (field1) values ('')"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from table1 where field1 =' '", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Debug.Print rs.EOF
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Although this article is about SQL Server, it provides an explanation: [INF: How SQL Server Compares Strings with Trailing Spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/topic/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces-b62b1a2d-27d3-4260-216d-a605719003b0).

Comment: Thank you Oliver. This answers my question.